# Возможно ли передать объект класса в конструктор другого класса?

Tags: php

Например, есть класс A c таким объектом:

```
$this->obj = new G();
```

Пытаюсь его передать в конструктор другого класса:

```
$template = new InitTemplate($this->obj);
```

В свою очередь в классе `InitTemplate` хочу использовать функции объекта `$this->obj`:

```
function __construct($inst)
{

        $this->outside = $inst;
        $this->outside->Callmethod();
}
```

Но `$inst` прилетает пустым, в чем ошибка?

Comment: А вы полный код покажите, как вы делаете. А так вам уже дан ответ как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне:

```
class A{
    function get(){
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}

class B{
    private $obj;

    function __construct($obj){
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    function get(){
        var_dump($this->obj->get());
    }
}

$b = new B(new A);
$b->get();

// Output: string(6) "A::get"
```